# WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have two comboBoxes, with names of Jobs and Departments as ItemSource.

jobComboBox items: m_job1, m_job2, n_job1, n_job2
departmentComboBox items: m_dep, n_dep

(such naming is just for understanding)

So, m_job can't be in n_dep and n_job can't be in m_dep.

I want jobComboBox.ItemSource to consist of relevant jobs due to departmentComboBox.SelectedItem without event handling.

ViewModel code:

```
private static List<string> job_names = new List<string>();
public List<string> Job_names
{
    get { return job_names; }
    set
    {
        job_names = value;
    }
}


private static List<string> dep_names = new List<string>();
public List<string> Dep_names
{
    get { return dep_names; }
    set
    {
        dep_names = value;
    }
}
```

Here I add some jobs and departments in ViewModel constructor.

```
public ViewModel()
{
    foreach (Jobs j in init_jobs)
    {
        if (j.fee == null)
        {
            job_names.Add(j.job_name);
        }
    }

    foreach (Departments d in init_deps)
    {
        if (d.workers_amount == null)
        {
            dep_names.Add(d.department_name);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="departmentComboBox" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Dep_names}" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_dep_name}"/>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="jComboBox"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Job_names}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_job_name}"/>
```

Tell me please, if my binding is right or not. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You would need to store the mapping of job and department somewhere. And use ICollectionViewSource to filter data on basis of one combobox selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `ICollectionView` as I have used in the code below:
(This code is just for information only, change it according to your requirement.)

**View:**

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentsView}"
            Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDepartment}" />

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding JobsView}"
            Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel and related classes:**

```
public abstract class DropDownItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Job : DropDownItem
{

}

public class Department : DropDownItem
{
    public bool DoesJobBelongsToDepartment(Job job)
    {
        return job?.Id % Id == 0;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<Job> jobs;
    private List<Department> departments;

    public ICollectionView JobsView { get; }
    public ICollectionView DepartmentsView { get; }

    private Department selectedDepartment;
    public Department SelectedDepartment
    {
        get { return selectedDepartment; }
        set
        {
            selectedDepartment = value;
            JobsView.Refresh();
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDepartment));
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        jobs = new List<Job>(Enumerable.Range(1, 21).Select(x => new Job { Id = x, Name = $"Job {x}" }));
        departments = new List<Department>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new Department{ Id = x, Name = $"Department {x}" }));

        DepartmentsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(departments);

        JobsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(jobs);
        JobsView.Filter = JobsViewFilter;
    }

    private bool JobsViewFilterPredicate(Object obj)
    {
        var job = obj as Job;
        return SelectedDepartment == null ? false
                                            : SelectedDepartment.DoesJobBelongsToDepartment(job);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

In the code above, I have 2 classes `Job` and `Department` to store information about job and department. In the `ViewModel` I'm initializing lists with few dummy values and I'm using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` to get default `ICollectionView` instance for the lists. Notice, I've applied filter for `JobsView` which will filter data based on `SelectedDepartment` using `JobsViewFilterPredicate` function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class for departments. The Department Class would have a JobNames property constaining a list of all the job names for the particular department. The Department Class would also contain a name property for the department. Dep_names would become a `List<Department>`.

Then you could change your XAML to this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="departmentComboBox" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Dep_names}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_dep_name}"/>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="jComboBox"
           ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=departmentComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.JobNames}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_job_name}"/>
```